# Problem finding constants after using DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have to solve a relatively simple PDE:
$$\frac{\phi_{xx}(x,y)}{A}+\frac{\phi_{yy}(x,y)}{B}=-2 \theta$$
where $A$, $B$, and $\theta$ are constants. The code that I used was

```
pde=1/Gy D[ϕ[x,y],{x,2}]+1/Gx D[ϕ[x,y],{y,2}]==-2θ
sol=DSolve[pde,ϕ[x,y],{x,y}]
(* (ϕ^(0,2))[x,y]/Gx+(ϕ^(2,0))[x,y]/Gy==-2 θ *)
(* {{ϕ[x,y]->-Gy x^2 θ+C[1][(Sqrt[-Gx Gy] x)/Gx+y]+C[2][-((Sqrt[-Gx Gy] x)/Gx)+y]}} *)
```

Firstly, I would like to ask how reliable this is. I'm still new to Mathematica so I'm not completely sure how well it handles second-order PDEs.

Now I would like to solve for `C[1]` and `C[2]`. I have BCs $\phi(\pm a,y)=\phi(x,\pm b)=0$ so I type in

```
ϕ2[x_,y_]=ϕ[x,y]/.sol[[1]]
Solve[ϕ2[a,b]==0&&ϕ2[-a,-b]==0,{C[1],C[2]}]
```

and I get out

```
(* -Gy x^2 θ+C[1][(Sqrt[-Gx Gy] x)/Gx+y]+C[2][-((Sqrt[-Gx Gy] x)/Gx)+y] *)
(* {{}} *)
```

I don't understand why Mathematica is giving me `{{}}`. Does that mean that there are no solutions? Am I typing in the constants wrong into `Solve`? I tried quitting the kernel and re-running the code several times but to no avail. I also tried to type in `Solve[ϕ2[a,y]==0&&ϕ2[-a,y]==0,{C[1],C[2]}]` and other combinations but nothing happened.

It would be simple to solve for `C[1]` and `C[2]` by hand but later I will need to deal with more complicated equations so I want to learn what mistake I made.

EDIT: I tried to type in the following

```
g[x_,y_]=-Gy x^2 \[Theta]+A[(Sqrt[-Gx Gy] x)/Gx+y]+B[(Gy x)/Sqrt[-Gx Gy]+y]
Solve[{g[a,y]==0},A]
```

but it still won't solve even for just `A`.

Comment: I realized that I didn't put {} in `Solve[\[Phi]2[a,b]==0&&\[Phi]2[-a,-b]==0,{C[1],C[2]}]` but even after adding the parenthesis around `\[Phi]2[a,b]==0&&\[Phi]2[-a,-b]==0` I still don't get a solution.

Comment: The return value `{{}}` of `Solve` signifies that "the solution set is full dimensional" (see documentation of `Solve`). The problem is that the solution of your PDE contains two functions `C[1]` and `C[2]`, and `Solve` can't solve for functions. You would need to supply your boundary conditions directly to `DSolve`, but I couldn't get it to work for now (you might have to use `NDSolve`). Note also that the way you've written the boundary conditions in code does not match what you've written in the text.

Comment: @Nasser My apologies, I got confused and changed the question appropriately.

Comment: @LukasLang I wrote those BCs because since the boundary is a rectangle, I thought it would be reasonable to assume that `ϕ2[a,b]==0`. I tried limits like I wrote in the question but got no answer.

How can I enter the BCs in DSolve?

Comment: @Nasser There should be a solution, I know that for a fact. One way to get it is to use a Fourier expansion $\phi=\sum _{k=1,3,(5)\text{...}}^{\infty } y Y_k \sin \left(\frac{(\pi  k) x}{a}\right)$ so the equation becomes $\frac{Y_k''}{B}-\frac{\left(\frac{\pi  k}{a}\right)^2 Y_k}{A}=-\frac{\pi  \theta }{8 k}$ which can then be solved. So Mathematica can't solve it?

Comment: While on this subject, I asked Mathematica to solve $\frac{y''(x)}{A}-\frac{\pi ^2 k^2 y(x)}{a^2 B}=-\frac{8 \theta }{\pi  k}$  and it gave me $\frac{8 a^2 B \theta }{\pi ^3 k^3}+c_1 e^{\frac{\pi  \sqrt{A} k x}{a \sqrt{B}}}+c_2 e^{-\frac{\pi  \sqrt{A} k x}{a \sqrt{B}}}$ which has an extra $B$ in the $\frac{8 a^2 B \theta }{\pi ^3 k^3}$ term that the solution in a paper does not have. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: You may get a numerical solution of such an equation. It may be, further, reduced to an equation with one control parameter, then you could easily tabulate the solution. If not, I only see the way to use Fourier-transform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is an analytical solution. The min/max only applies to Laplace PDE, not Poisson.

Here is the analytical solution. I verified it using Mathematica's `NDSolve` and it agrees. So I do not know why Mathematica `DSolve` could not solve it. May be in version 12 it will.

### Analytical solution

solve
\begin{align*}
\frac{u_{xx}}{A}+\frac{u_{yy}}{B}  &  =-2\theta\\
Bu_{xx}+Au_{yy}  &  =-2\theta AB\\
&  =C
\end{align*}

Where $C=-2\theta AB$ is a new constant. With boundary conditions

\begin{align*}
u\left(  x,-b\right)   &  =0\\
u\left(  x,b\right)   &  =0\\
u\left(  -a,y\right)   &  =0\\
u\left(  a,y\right)   &  =0
\end{align*}

To simplify solution, shift the rectangle so its lower left corner on the
origin. Let $\tilde{x}=x+a$, and $\tilde{y}=y+b$. The boundary conditions becomes

\begin{align*}
u\left(  \tilde{x},0\right)   &  =0\\
u\left(  \tilde{x},2b\right)   &  =0\\
u\left(  0,\tilde{y}\right)   &  =0\\
u\left(  2a,\tilde{y}\right)   &  =0
\end{align*}

And the pde becomes $Bu_{\tilde{x}\tilde{x}}+Au_{\tilde{y}\tilde{y}}=C$.
Instead of keep writing $\tilde{x},\tilde{y}$, will use $x,y$, but remember
that these are shifted version. At the end, we shift back.

Hence the PDE to solve is  $Bu_{xx}+Au_{yy}=C$ with BC

\begin{align*}
u\left(  x,0\right)   &  =0\\
u\left(  x,2b\right)   &  =0\\
u\left(  0,y\right)   &  =0\\
u\left(  2a,y\right)   &  =0
\end{align*}

Using eigenfunction expansion method. Let
\begin{equation}
u\left(  x,y\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}\left(  y\right)  X_{n}\left(
x\right)  \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Where $X_{n}\left(  x\right)  $ is eigenfunctions for $X^{\prime\prime}\left(
x\right)  +\lambda_{n}X\left(  x\right)  =0$ with boundary conditions
$X\left(  0\right)  =X\left(  2a\right)  =0$. This has eigenfunctions as
$X_{n}\left(  x\right)  =\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  $ with
eigenvalues $\lambda_{n}=\left(  \frac{n\pi}{2a}\right)  ^{2}$ \ for
$n=1,2,\cdots$.

Substituting (1) into the PDE $Bu_{xx}+Au_{yy}=C$ gives

$$
B\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}\left(  y\right)  X_{n}^{\prime\prime}\left(
x\right)  +A\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}^{\prime\prime}\left(  y\right)
X_{n}\left(  x\right)  =C
$$

Expanding $C$ (a constant) as Fourier sine series the above becomes

$$
B\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}\left(  y\right)  X_{n}^{\prime\prime}\left(
x\right)  +A\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}^{\prime\prime}\left(  y\right)
X_{n}\left(  x\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q_{n}X_{n}\left(  x\right)
$$

But $X_{n}^{\prime\prime}\left(  x\right)  =-\lambda_{n}X_{n}\left(  x\right)
$, hence the above becomes

\begin{align}
-B\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{n}b_{n}\left(  y\right)  X_{n}\left(  x\right)
+A\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}^{\prime\prime}\left(  y\right)  X_{n}\left(
x\right)   &  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q_{n}X_{n}\left(  x\right)  \nonumber\\
Ab_{n}^{\prime\prime}\left(  y\right)  -B\lambda_{n}b_{n}\left(  y\right)   &
=q_{n}\tag{1A}
\end{align}

But

\begin{align*}
C  & =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q_{n}X_{n}\left(  x\right)  \\
\int_{0}^{2a}CX_{n}\left(  x\right)  dx  & =q_{n}\int_{0}^{2a}X_{n}^{2}\left(
x\right)  dx\\
\int_{0}^{2a}C\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  dx  & =q_{n}\int
_{0}^{2a}\sin^{2}\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  dx\\
\frac{-C}{\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}}\left(  \left(  -1\right)  ^{n}-1\right)    &
=q_{n}a\\
q_{n}  & =\frac{-C}{a\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}}\left(  \left(  -1\right)
^{n}-1\right)
\end{align*}

Hence (1A) becomes

$$
Ab_{n}^{\prime\prime}\left(  y\right)  -B\lambda_{n}b_{n}\left(  y\right)
=\frac{-C}{a\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}}\left(  \left(  -1\right)  ^{n}-1\right)
$$

This is standard second order linear ODE. The solution is

$$
b_{n}\left(  y\right)  =D_{n}e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}y}+E_{n}
e^{-\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}y}+\frac{C}{aB\lambda_{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}
}\left(  \left(  -1\right)  ^{n}-1\right)
$$

Using the above in (1) gives the solution

\begin{equation}
u\left(  x,y\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(  D_{n}e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}
{A}\lambda_{n}}y}+E_{n}e^{-\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}y}+\frac{C}
{aB\lambda_{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}}\left(  \left(  -1\right)  ^{n}-1\right)
\right)  X_{n}\left(  x\right)  \tag{1A}
\end{equation}

We now need to find $D_{n},E_{n}$.

Case $n$ even

When $n$ is even $\left(  \left(  -1\right)  ^{n}-1\right)  =0$ and the
solution (1A) becomes

$$
u\left(  x,y\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(  D_{n}e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}
{A}\lambda_{n}}y}+E_{n}e^{-\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}y}\right)
X_{n}\left(  x\right)
$$

At $y=0$ the above gives

$$
0=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(  D_{n}+E_{n}\right)  \sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda
_{n}}x\right)
$$

Therefore

\begin{equation}
D_{n}+E_{n}=0 \tag{2}
\end{equation}

And at $y=2b$

$$
0=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(  D_{n}e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}2b}
+E_{n}e^{-\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}2b}\right)  \sin\left(  \sqrt
{\lambda_{n}}x\right)
$$

Therefore

\begin{equation}
D_{n}e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}2b}+E_{n}e^{-\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda
_{n}}2b}=0 \tag{3}
\end{equation}

From (2,3) we see that $D_{n}=E_{n}=0$, Hence $u\left(  x,y\right)  =0$ when
$n$ even.

Case $n$ odd

When $n$ is odd $\left(  \left(  -1\right)  ^{n}-1\right)  =-2$ and the
solution (1A) becomes

$$
u\left(  x,y\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(  D_{n}e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}
{A}\lambda_{n}}y}+E_{n}e^{-\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}y}-\frac{2C}
{aB\lambda_{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)  X_{n}\left(  x\right)
$$

At $y=0$ the above gives

$$
0=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(  D_{n}+E_{n}-\frac{2C}{aB\lambda_{n}^{\frac{3}{2}
}}\right)  \sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)
$$

Therefore

\begin{equation}
D_{n}+E_{n}-\frac{2C}{aB\lambda_{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}}=0\tag{4}
\end{equation}

And at $y=2b$

$$
0=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(  D_{n}e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}2b}
+E_{n}e^{-\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}2b}-\frac{2C}{aB\lambda_{n}^{\frac
{3}{2}}}\right)  \sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)
$$

Therefore

\begin{equation}
D_{n}e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}2b}+E_{n}e^{-\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda
_{n}}2b}-\frac{2C}{aB\lambda_{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}}=0\tag{5}
\end{equation}

Solving (4,5) for $D_{n},E_{n}$ gives

\begin{align*}
D_{n} &  =\frac{2C}{aB\lambda_{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}}\frac{1}{1+e^{\sqrt{\frac
{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}2b}}\\
E_{n} &  =\frac{2C}{aB\lambda_{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}}\frac{e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}
{A}\lambda_{n}}2b}}{1+e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}2b}}
\end{align*}

Therefore the final solution from (1A) becomes

\begin{align*}
u\left(  x,y\right)    & =\sum_{n=1,3,5,\cdots}^{\infty}\left(  D_{n}
e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}y}+E_{n}e^{-\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}
y}-\frac{2C}{aB\lambda_{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)  X_{n}\left(  x\right)  \\
& =\sum_{n=1,3,5,\cdots}^{\infty}\left(  \left(  \frac{2C}{aB\lambda
_{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}}\frac{1}{1+e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}2b}}\right)
e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}y}+\left(  \frac{2C}{aB\lambda_{n}^{\frac
{3}{2}}}\frac{e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}2b}}{1+e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}
{A}\lambda_{n}}2b}}\right)  e^{-\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}y}-\frac
{2C}{aB\lambda_{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)  \sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}
}x\right)
\end{align*}

Where $\lambda_{n}=\left(  \frac{n\pi}{2a}\right)  ^{2}$. Switching back to
original coordinates using $\tilde{x}=x+a$, and $\tilde{y}=y+b$, then the
above is

$$
u\left(  x,y\right)  =\sum_{n=1,3,5,\cdots}^{\infty}\left(  \left(  \frac
{2C}{aB\lambda_{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}}\frac{1}{1+e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}
}2b}}\right)  e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}\left(  y+b\right)  }+\left(
\frac{2C}{aB\lambda_{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}}\frac{e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}
}2b}}{1+e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}2b}}\right)  e\left(  ^{-\sqrt
{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}y+b}\right)  -\frac{2C}{aB\lambda_{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}
}\right)  \sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}\left(  x+a\right)  \right)
$$

Where $C=-2\theta AB$, hence

\begin{align*}
u\left(  x,y\right)   &  =\sum_{n=1,3,5,\cdots}^{\infty}\left(  \left(
\frac{-4\theta AB}{aB\lambda_{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}}\frac{1}{1+e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}
{A}\lambda_{n}}2b}}\right)  e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}\left(
y+b\right)  }+\left(  \frac{-4\theta AB}{aB\lambda_{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\frac{e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}2b}}{1+e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}
}2b}}\right)  e^{-\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}\left(  y+b\right)  }
+\frac{4\theta AB}{aB\lambda_{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)  \sin\left(
\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}\left(  x+a\right)  \right)  \\
&  =\sum_{n=1,3,5,\cdots}^{\infty}\left(  \left(  \frac{-4\theta A}
{a\lambda_{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}}\frac{1}{1+e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}2b}
}\right)  e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}\left(  y+b\right)  }+\left(
\frac{-4\theta A}{a\lambda_{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}}\frac{e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}
\lambda_{n}}2b}}{1+e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}2b}}\right)  e^{-\sqrt
{\frac{B}{A}\lambda_{n}}\left(  y+b\right)  }+\frac{4\theta A}{a\lambda
_{n}^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)  \sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}\left(  x+a\right)
\right)
\end{align*}

### Verification against NDsolve

**Test 1**

```
ClearAll[a, b, A, B, z, n, x, y, u, lam]; 
a = 1; b = 5; A = 1; B = 2; theta = 3; 
(*analytic*)
lam = ((n*Pi)/(2*a))^2; 
term1 = 1/(1 + Exp[Sqrt[(B/A)*lam]*2*b]); 
term2 = (4*theta*A)/(a*lam^(3/2)); 
mysol[maxTerms_, x_, y_] := 
  Sum[(((-term2)*term1)*
       Exp[Sqrt[(B/A)*lam]*(y + b)] + ((-term2)*term1*
         Exp[Sqrt[(B/A)*lam]*(2*b)])*
       Exp[(-Sqrt[(B/A)*lam])*(y + b)] + term2)*
         Sin[Sqrt[lam]*(x + a)], {n, 1, maxTerms, 2}]; 
(*numeric*)
pde = D[u[x, y], {x, 2}]/A + D[u[x, y], {y, 2}]/B == -2*theta; 
bc = {u[x, -b] == 0, u[x, b] == 0, u[-a, y] == 0, u[a, y] == 0}; 
sol = NDSolve[{pde, bc}, u, {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}];
```

Compare 3D

```
Grid[{{Plot3D[Evaluate[u[x, y] /. sol], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, 
    PlotLabel -> "Numerical"], 
   Plot3D[mysol[15, x, y], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, 
    PlotLabel -> "Analytical"]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

compare contour

```
Grid[{{ContourPlot[Evaluate[u[x, y] /. sol], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, 
    PlotLabel -> "NDSolve"], 
   ContourPlot[mysol[25, x, y], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, 
    PlotLabel -> "Analytical"]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Test 2**

```
ClearAll[a, b, A, B, z, n, x, y, u, lam]; 
a = 3; b = 18; A = 7; B = -2; theta = -10; 
lam = ((n*Pi)/(2*a))^2; 
term1 = 1/(1 + Exp[Sqrt[(B/A)*lam]*2*b]); 
term2 = (4*theta*A)/(a*lam^(3/2)); 
mysol[maxTerms_, x_, y_] := 
  Sum[(((-term2)*term1)*
       Exp[Sqrt[(B/A)*lam]*(y + b)] + ((-term2)*term1*
         Exp[Sqrt[(B/A)*lam]*(2*b)])*
       Exp[(-Sqrt[(B/A)*lam])*(y + b)] + term2)*
         Sin[Sqrt[lam]*(x + a)], {n, 1, maxTerms, 2}]; 

pde = D[u[x, y], {x, 2}]/A + D[u[x, y], {y, 2}]/B == -2*theta; 
bc = {u[x, -b] == 0, u[x, b] == 0, u[-a, y] == 0, u[a, y] == 0}; 
sol = NDSolve[{pde, bc}, u, {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}];
```

Compare 3D

```
Grid[{{Plot3D[Evaluate[u[x, y] /. sol], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, 
    PlotLabel -> "Numerical"], 
   Plot3D[mysol[15, x, y], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, 
    PlotLabel -> "Analytical"]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare contour

```
Grid[{{ContourPlot[Evaluate[u[x, y] /. sol], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, 
    PlotLabel -> "NDSolve"], 
   ContourPlot[mysol[25, x, y], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, 
    PlotLabel -> "Analytical"]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution! It gave me a serious lesson in maths! I tried to check the analytical solution against the solution that I have and there is a problem but I don't understand where. The next step is to calculate $GJ=2\int_{-b}^b \left(\int_{-a}^a u(x,y) \, dx\right) \, dy$ then $\beta=\frac{GJ}{Ab^{3}a}$. Setting $A=B$, $b=a$ and $z=1$ should produce $\beta=0.1405$ but the analytical solution above does not unfortunately.

Comment: @enea19 No problem, it is was an interesting PDE. I verified the analytical solution using different values for the parameters and they all agree with Mathematica's `NDSolve`. So it is possible the other solution you have has some typo in it.

Comment: @enea19 may be you are doing something wrong with the integration code. I do not know.